# PHP: HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: php

How can I tell if a php page was accessed via http or https?

Comment: If would be useful to know more about your PHP configuration (in which server it's running, for example).

Comment: The answers below that only refer to checking $_SERVER["HTTPS"] are not complete.   Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-youre-using-https-without-serverhttps for a complete answer.

Answer (score 53):

If the request was sent with HTTPS you will have a extra parameter in the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal - $_SERVER['HTTPS']. You can check if it is set or not

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it doesn't always work, as the `$_SERVER` documentation says: "The entries in this array are created by the web server. There is no guarantee that every web server will provide any of these; servers may omit some, or provide others not listed here."

Comment: If the server is properly configured, is shouldn't be a problem. Better to try this approach first and resort to hacks if it fails

Comment: @EranGalperin, You're missing the point. A properly configured server is allowed to omit $_SERVER entries. It's explicitly allowed in the documentation.

Comment: Under some configurations $_SERVER['HTTPS'] will return 'off' when it is HTTP, so that needs to be tested as per Aelios' answer.

Comment: @Pacerier: Real life does not work as described in the documentation - no web server that omits $_SERVER['HTTPS'] would be used in any production environment and such a behavior would be filed as a bug, considered as a bug and fixed as a bug - nobody cares whether the documentation says otherwise.

Answer (score 48):

If your request is sent by HTTPS you will have an extra server variable named 'HTTPS'

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off') { //HTTPS }
```

Comment: Should use this answer when using ISAPI with IIS.

Comment: You can also use `preg_match('/https|HTTPS/',$_SERVER ["REQUEST_SCHEME"]) == 1`

Comment: @jking `/https|HTTPS/` obviously overlooks the `i` pattern modifier as a matter of cleaner scripting and best practice.

Answer (score 30):

```
$protocol = strtolower(substr($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"],0,5))=='https'?'https':'http';

$protocol = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https' : 'http';
```

These should both work

Comment: `$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']` starts with `'HTTP'` in both the cases.

Answer (score 4):

This can get more complicated depending on where PHP sits in your environment, since your question is quite broad. This may depend on whether there's a load-balancer and how it's configured. Here are are a few related questions:

- [How can I prevent access to PHP files if the caller isn't using HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729497/how-can-i-prevent-access-to-php-files-if-the-caller-isnt-using-https)
- [Detecting HTTPS vs HTTP on server sending back nothing useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552162/detecting-https-vs-http-on-server-sending-back-nothing-useful)

Comment: These SO links look they could have been just as easily posted as comment under the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']
```

This will contain a 'non-empty' value if the request was sent through HTTPS

[PHP Server Variables](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by checking the value of `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` (it should only be set when using https).

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php.

Comment: so if I use HTTPS and the server does not create this $_SERVER['HTTPS'] does that mean it's a fake HTTPS?