# How to check whether the page is call from http or https in php

Tags: php

Just wondering, will it be possible we can check whether the page is call from http or https in php?

Example:
If I call to a page call customer.php by the following link http://customer.php, will it be possible to check in php and tell the page is from http.. also if I call the page from the following link https://customer.php, will it be possible to check in php and tell the page is from https??

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: HTTP or HTTPS? How can one tell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042962/php-http-or-https-how-can-one-tell)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to look at:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    // https is enabled
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also check for `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']`  as  **[written here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)**

> As opposed to HTTP URLs that begin
>   with "http://" and use port 80 by
>   default, HTTPS URLs begin with
>   "https://" and use port 443 by
>   default.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    // do stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the request was sent with HTTPS you will have a extra parameter in the `$_SERVER` superglobal `- $_SERVER['HTTPS'].` You can check if it is set or not

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) ) {
```