# How to define was page requested over https or http?

Tags: http, https, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: HTTP or HTTPS? How can one tell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042962/php-http-or-https-how-can-one-tell)

Is there a way to define this?

$_SERVER superglogal doesn't provide such info. Even only it's ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your request is sent by HTTPS you will have an extra server variable named 'HTTPS'

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'] )  && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ) 
{
   echo 'HTTPS';
}
else
{
  echo 'HTTP';
}
```

Comment: One little problem here. Elements of `$_SERVER` are generated by the web server, so it maybe missing `https` entry because server does not generate one while requested over `https://`.

Comment: **Note** that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be *'off'* if the request was not made through the HTTPS protocol, so the test should be `isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off'` to be cross-api.