# Htaccess redirection to https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https

I am using the following httaccess content, to force rewrite the url's to use https instead of http

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L]
```

But it's always getting,
The page isn't redirecting properly

```
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address
in a way that will never complete.     
This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept
cookies.
```

I've used many other solutions but always getting this...

Comment: SERVER_PORT might not be conclusive as test here, See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042962/php-http-or-https-how-can-one-tell

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below for .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#uncomment the below two line if you need to append www
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
# RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```