# Interactive program in the command line

Tags: php, mysql, command-line, https, cmd

I would like to create an interactive program in the command line for windows. I would like to use PHP as the language. I know that there is the command line download on [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), but I do not believe that it supports mysql, or any kind of database. I also do not believe that there is HTTPS requests possible. I would appreciate anyone who could help me to solve this problem. I apprecite the help in advance. Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042962/php-http-or-https

Comment: Is there any other possible drivers? for example, I prefer to use mysqli. Also, I know that HTTPS is not set because when i run my program, it does not print out the expected variables. No error occurs.

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Do you have something like WAMP installed?

Comment: I do not. I have XAMPP Installed on my server. I have the server program down, but I would like to create a CMD client application using PHP. Is this possible?