# How to accept only HTTPS requests and reject HTTP?

Tags: php, api, https

*Hello i have my site hosted on Hostinger and i enabled it to force HTTPS, so when people writes http://example.com it goes to https://example.com.
I have an API that handles a POST from my program.
I already have my api handling requests but i don't know how to "filter" HTTPS.
Right now any request (http or https) are accepted by my API, but i want it to ignore or block HTTP request, and only answer to HTTPS.*

@edit: 
Used suggestions on comments and came with the following:
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

When i do an HTTPS request it works, but when i do an HTTP request, it makes the request but when i echo the variables sent on the body, they are empty.

Comment: using .htaccess

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

Comment: Hello, i already have the following: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
should i replace that with what you wrote?

Comment: Add this at the begin of your API file
`if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') return;`
this will reject requests made over HTTP!

Answer (score 1):

in .htaccess

```js
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
        # Redirection to HTTPS
            RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
            RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
        .................
   </IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I encountered a problem that i will update on the main question.

Answer (score 0):

This should reject HTTP requests with a 403

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tag php, you can also use [$_SERVER['HTTPS']](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4042984/451321):

```
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    die 'You are not allowed to use http';
}
```