# Why isn't _SERVER["HTTPS"] set to 1?

Tags: php, apache, webserver

My site has an SSL cert and I'm hitting https://mysite.com/info.php, but under the PHP Variables section _SERVER["HTTPS"] is not being reported. I believe this is causing a problem with a Drupal site where some URLs are being written to the page as https://... where others are being written as http://...

What determines if _SERVER["HTTPS"] is set?

---

**EDIT:** This may be the answer to my problem [Detecting HTTPS vs HTTP on server sending back nothing useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552162/detecting-https-vs-http-on-server-sending-back-nothing-useful). Could be a load balancer issue

Comment: What webserver is this running on?

Comment: Apache and I'm pretty sure the load balancer is the issue. IT department mentioned that they specifically set the PHP variable HTTP_USESSL. The Secure Pages module was altered to check that variable instead of HTTPS.

Comment: Instead of altering a default module (which will break on the next upgrade), you might want to consider doing `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USESSL'] ) ? 'YES' : '' )`, somewhere in a boostrap file instead, so future upgrades won't break.

Comment: I agree...inherited code. I'll likely make a change like this in future so the module itself isn't hacked. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that because of the Load Balancer, which handles the SSL encryption/decryption the Web Server doesn't get $_SERVER["HTTPS"], but $_SERVER["HTTP_USESSL"] is set and can be used as a flash for SSL traffic.

Answer (score 7):

It says in the documentation `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`

```
Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
```

so

```
function checkHTTPS() {
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
        if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off')
            return true; //https
        else
            return false; //http
     else
        if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
            return true; //https
        else
            return false; //http
}
```

Comment: Ya, but what I'm saying is when I look at the output of phpinfo(); it doesn't show anything for _SERVER["HTTPS"]...it's not set at all, but it should be as far as I can tell (SSL cert and url is https://...)

Comment: That depends on your server configuration (Apache, nginx, etc) and their variables passed to PHP. I guess another way to do it is `$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443'`.

Comment: Here i made a function (not tested)

Comment: SSL port is 443 in most cases, but not always.

Answer (score 7):

Behind a proxy / load balancer

$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] was always 80

$_SERVER["HTTPS"]  and  $_SERVER["HTTP_USESSL"] were NULL

I used $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] that return http or https

Comment: Its great solutions. working like a charm for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Arnaud Hallais' post, the only way I managed to get the correct protocol on my localhost (apache/mac), testing server (apache/linux) and production site (iis/win) was with:

```
define("PROTOCOL", isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] : ((isset( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) && strtolower( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] ) == "on" ) ? 'https' : 'http'));
```